# How to prevent division by zero?

Tags: c#, linq, divide-by-zero

```
ads = ads.Where(x => (x.Amount - x.Price) / (x.Amount / 100) >= filter.Persent);
```

if x.Amount == 0 I have error "Divide by zero error encountered."

like me in this request is to avoid?

**update:**

this helped, but I do not like the decision:

```
ads = ads.Where(x => (x.Amount - x.Price) / ((x.Amount / 100)==0?0.1:(x.Amount / 100)) >= filter.Persent);
```

there is another way?

Comment: Can't you put it in an if statement and only run that code when x.Amount > 0 ?

Comment: I think you should wonder why do you have items with 0 Amount :P

Comment: In what business is `Amount - Price` a meaningful quantity?

Comment: @Adrian Iftode, this field can be set to 0

Comment: @Henk Holterman, Russian is what we know bad English

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ads = ads.Where(x => x.Amount != 0 &&
                    (x.Amount - x.Price) / (x.Amount / 100) >= filter.Persent);
```

Comment: `x.Amount > 0` seems just a tad safer.

Comment: @simplydenis: What would not help?

Comment: @simple denis why wouldn't it help? do you need to include items with amout == 0? in that case what should D be in (-x.Price / D) >= filter.Persent (btw shouldn't that be percent as in %?)

Comment: @HenkHolterman who's to say which rules guides the business after all Amount - Price makes sense in this particular case why would a negative Amount then? (though in general I agree with you)

Comment: @simplydenis: What error? (I have seen the update to the question: *do not do that, it looks really bad*. Such solutions indicate that the problem has not been understood well enough, or that you are trying to do something which does not make sense. What is your goal here? Don't forget about the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 32):

Of course, you can always implement a generic safe division method and use it all the way

```
using System;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    static public class NumericExtensions
    {
        static public decimal SafeDivision(this decimal Numerator, decimal Denominator)
        {
            return (Denominator == 0) ? 0 : Numerator / Denominator;
        }
    }

}
```

I have chosen **decimal** type because it addresses all non nullable numeric types that I am aware of.

Usage:

```
var Numerator = 100;
var Denominator = 0;

var SampleResult1 = NumericExtensions.SafeDivision(Numerator , Denominator );

var SampleResult2 = Numerator.SafeDivision(Denominator);
```

Comment: +1 for the thought, but I don't think it should return zero if the denominator is zero.... the actual value is closer to +-infinity unless the numerator is also zero, in which case it is undefined.

Comment: Yes, user420667, I agree with you. While the suggested solution may not fit all real-world situations, I think it fits most of them. Nonetheless, one should always weight the consequences on using a fallback value. Anyway, thanks for your thought :D

Comment: I personally would return Numerator as the fallback value because many times as a programmer, you are grabbing counts from the DB that you want to divide.  If COUNT(N) = 8 and COUNT(D) = 0, just because D has not happened yet, returning the value 8 is closer to 8 / 1, which is your closest real number.